# Test push notifications using Universal Windows App

Tags: azure, push-notification, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, azure-notificationhub

I have been using this MSDN tutorial ([Tutorial: Send notifications to Universal Windows Platform apps using Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification)) to test the notification hub. The issue is it is asking me to create an app in Windows Store for which I need to register for Microsoft developer and it seems to be paid service. I'm trying to find an alternative here to get Package SID and Security Key for Windows (WNS) settings to register for an Azure Notification Hub. Please suggest.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Dev Center requires an account with a one time payment as specified on the [Register to be an App Developer page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/register/).